# RuntimeException for creating the table in SQLite in Android

Tags: android

```
package com.example.databasestorage;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DB_NAME = "Adj";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
public static final String USER_DETAILS_TABLE = "user_details_table";
public static SQLiteDatabase db;


public static final String CREATE_USER_DETAILS_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE "
        + "user_details_table" + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT"
        + "user_name TEXT NOT NULL " + "password TEXT NOT NULL"
        + "sex TEXT NOT NULL" + " email TEXT NOT NULL"
        + " remember_me TEXT ); ";

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

public static boolean DataBaseOpen() {
    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(null);
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return (db == null) ? false : true;
}

public void DataBaseClose() {
    if (db != null)
        db.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_DETAILS_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + USER_DETAILS_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}

}






package com.adjetter.databasestorage;

 import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText userNameEditText;
EditText passwordEditText;
// EditText confirmPasswordEditTex;
EditText emailEditText;
TextView sex_textview;
String newPath;
Button submit;
CheckBox checkbox;
ImageButton facebookLogin;
ImageButton googleLogin;
View layout;
String picturePath = null;
private RadioGroup radioSexGroup;
SQLiteDatabase db;
DBHelper dbHelper;
String checkboxStatus = "false";
private RadioButton radioSexButton;


AlertDialog.Builder builder;
int selectedGender;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    userNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    passwordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    emailEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    sex_textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sex_textview);
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_button);
    radioSexGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RG1);
    checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();


    submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            selectedGender = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            radioSexButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedGender);

            validate();

            if(checkbox.isChecked()){
                checkboxStatus = "true";
            } else{
                checkboxStatus = "false";
            }

            if(validate()){
//              DBHelper.DataBaseOpen();
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(5);
                cv.put("user_name", userNameEditText.getText().toString());
                cv.put("password", passwordEditText.getText().toString());
                cv.put("sex", radioSexButton.getText().toString());
                cv.put("email", emailEditText.getText().toString());
                cv.put("remember_me", checkboxStatus);
                db.insert(DBHelper.USER_DETAILS_TABLE, null, cv);
            }
        }

    });

}

public boolean validate() {
    Validation.isEmailAddress(emailEditText, true);
    Validation.isUserName(userNameEditText, true);
    Validation.isPassword(passwordEditText, true);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

**LogCat:**

```
10-09 13:41:49.807: E/SQLiteLog(16458): (1) near "AUTOINCREMENTuser_name": syntax error
10-09 13:41:49.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16458): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-09 13:41:49.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16458): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.adjetter.databasestorage/com.adjetter.databasestorage.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AUTOINCREMENTuser_name": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE user_details_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENTuser_name TEXT NOT NULL password TEXT NOT NULLsex TEXT NOT NULL email TEXT NOT NULL remember_me TEXT );
10-09 13:41:49.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16458):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
10-09 13:41:49.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16458):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
10-09 13:41:49.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16458):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
10-09 13:41:49.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16458):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
10-09 13:41:49.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16458):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
10-09 13:41:49.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16458):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
10-09 13:41:49.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16458):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
10-09 13:41:49.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16458):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 13:41:49.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16458):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-09 13:41:49.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16458):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
10-09 13:41:49.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16458):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
10-09 13:41:49.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16458):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-09 13:41:49.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16458): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AUTOINCREMENTuser_name": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE user_details_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENTuser_name TEXT NOT NULL password TEXT NOT NULLsex TEXT NOT NULL email TEXT NOT NULL remember_me TEXT );
10-09 13:41:49.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16458):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
10-09 13:41:49.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16458):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:886)
10-09 13:41:49.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16458):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:497)
10-09 13:41:49.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16458):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
10-09 13:41:49.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16458):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
10-09 13:41:49.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16458):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
10-09 13:41:49.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16458):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1663)
10-09 13:41:49.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16458):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
10-09 13:41:49.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16458):    at com.adjetter.databasestorage.DBHelper.onCreate(DBHelper.java:38)
10-09 13:41:49.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16458):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
10-09 13:41:49.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16458):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
10-09 13:41:49.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16458):    at com.adjetter.databasestorage.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:60)
10-09 13:41:49.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16458):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
10-09 13:41:49.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16458):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1084)
10-09 13:41:49.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16458):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
10-09 13:41:49.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16458):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: `" (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT"
        + "user_name TEXT NOT NULL "` set a space before user_name. I would suggest you to lock the statement and try it in the sqlite browser. And have a look at your errors `near "AUTOINCREMENTuser_name": `

Comment: Next time you write a question... if you expect someone to take the time to answer it for you how about finding the time and decency to actually 'ask' a question as ooposed to pasting your error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate the column declarations with commas.

```
public static final String CREATE_USER_DETAILS_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE "
    + "user_details_table (" 
    + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
    + "user_name TEXT NOT NULL, " 
    + "password TEXT NOT NULL, "
    + "sex TEXT NOT NULL, " 
    + "email TEXT NOT NULL, "
    + "remember_me TEXT ); ";
```

P.S.: To avoid a downvote next time, you may want to actually ask a question. That comes across more friendly than just a dump of your code and log.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the values with commas, like

```
 " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
    + "user_name TEXT NOT NULL, "
```

Also set a space behind each comma.